# Halley Method proof

Tags: analysis

$x_{n+1}$= $x_n$ - ${f(x_n)\over f'(x_n)-(f(x_n)f''(x_n)/2f'(x_n))}$

Let $m$ be a positive integer, Show that applying Halley's method to the function $f(x)= x^m -k$ gives

$$x_{n+1}={(m-1)(x_n)^m + (m+1)k \over (m+1)(x_n)^m + (m-1) k} * x_n$$

I really struggle with showing that. Should I just build $f'(x)$ and $f''(x)$ and then start calculating? I mean I even tried this but I am stuck.

Comment: You have the right idea; just find $f'$ and $f''$ so that you can put it into the formula. Then, simplify the expression

Comment: $x_{n+1} = x_n - {x^m - k \over mx^{m-1} - { 2(x^m - k) -1) \over 2}}$

I am stuck here. Could you give me a hint?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use $y$ for $x_{n+1}$ and $x$ for $x_n$ to keep the formulas sowewhat more compact. The derivatives are:
$$f(x)=x^m-k,\; f'(x)=mx^{m-1},\; f''(x)=m(m-1)x^{m-2},\; f''(x)/f'(x)=(m-1)/x$$
Plugging this into the Halley formula
$$y = x - \frac{f(x)}{f'(x) - f''(x)/f'(x)f(x)/2}$$
gives

$$y = x - \frac{f(x)}{mx^{m-1} - (m-1)/2x(x^m-k)}$$

$$  = x - \frac{2x(x^m-k)}{2mx^m - (m-1)(x^m-k)}$$

$$  = x - \frac{2x(x^m-k)}{2mx^m - mx^m + mk + x^m - k}$$

$$  = x - \frac{2x(x^m-k)}{mx^m + mk + x^m -k}$$

$$  = x - \frac{2x(x^m-k)}{m(x^m+k) -(k-x^m)}$$

$$  = x\Big(1- \frac{2(x^m-k)}{m(x^m+k) - (k-x^m)}\Big)$$

$$  = x\frac{m(x^m+k) - (k-x^m) - 2(x^m-k)}{m(x^m+k) - (k-x^m)}$$

$$  = x\frac{mx^m + mk - k + x^m - 2x^m + 2k}{m(x^m+k) - (k-x^m)}$$

$$  = x\frac{mx^m + mk - x^m + k}{m(x^m+k) - (k-x^m)}$$

and finally
$$ y = x \frac{(m-1)x^m + (m+1)k}{(m+1)x^m +(m-1)k}$$

IMO the form
$$ y = x \frac{m(k+x^m) + (k-x^m)}{m(k+x^m) - (k-x^m)}$$
has the advantage that you work with the current error $x^m-k.$

Answer (score 0):

We have:

- $f(x) = x^m - k$
- $f'(x) = mx^{m-1}$
- $f''(x) = m(m-1)x^{m-2}$

So, applying the method gives us
$$
x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{x_n^m - k}{mx_n^{m-1} - m(m-1)(x_n^{2m-2} - kx_n^{m-2})/(2mx_n^{m-1})}
$$
Now, this is a fairly elaborate expression, so I'm going to simplify it one piece at a time.  In particular, we start with the denominator
$$
mx_n^{m-1} - m(m-1)(x_n^{2m-2} - kx_n^{m-2})/(2mx_n^{m-1}) \\= 
\frac{2m^2x_n^{2m-2} - (m^2 - m)(x_n^{2m-2} - kx_n^{m-2})}{2mx_n^{m-1}} \\=
\frac{(m^2 + m)x_n^{2m-2} + k(m^2 - m)x_n^{m-2}}{2mx_n^{m-1}} \\= 
\frac{(m+1)x_n^{m} + k(m-1)}{2x_n}
$$
So, we may now rewrite our original expression as
$$
x_n - \frac{x_n^m - k}{mx_n^{m-1} - m(m-1)x_n^{2m-2}/(2mx_n^{{m-1}})} = \\
x_n - (x_n^m - k)\cdot \frac{2x_n}{(m+1)x_n^{m} + k(m-1)} =  \\
\left(1 - (x_n^m - k)\cdot \frac{2}{(m+1)x_n^{m} + k(m-1)}\right)\cdot x_n
$$
That should be enough to get you started.